# \newcommand in tikz picture options

Tags: macros, tikz-styles

I want to insert a `\newcommand` in the style options of my `tikzpictures` for more efficiency. However, it produces an error, although the string itself is correct and works when being inserted directly in the style options. What is to be done to make it work? Thx a lot!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    
\newcommand{\ors}{overlay,remember picture,shift={(current page.west)}}

\ors

\begin{tikzpicture}[\ors]
    \node[rectangle,fill=red,anchor=north west] at (4,0){TEST};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to expand `\ors` before passing it to TikZ, for example with `\expanded{\noexpand\begin{tikzpicture}[\ors]}`.  But the right way with TikZ is to use a style:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\tikzset{ors/.style = {overlay,remember picture,shift={(current page.west)}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ors]
    \node[rectangle,fill=red,anchor=north west] at (4,0){TEST};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The cleaner way is to use [LaTeXer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569403/227987). However, there are situations in which you really want to use a macro. Then you can use

```
style/.expanded=\macro
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    
\newcommand{\ors}{overlay,remember picture,shift={(current page.west)}}

\ors

\begin{tikzpicture}[style/.expanded=\ors]
    \node[rectangle,fill=red,anchor=north west] at (4,0){TEST};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, `/.expanded`! Cool!